# Como salvar informações "não seriais" no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Seguinte, sou designer e to tendo que me virar aqui nos back-end da vida no que me é possível fazer, então peço perdão por usar "não seriais"...

Sei que no Wordpress é possível salvar os dados usando post type(custom post type).
Mas eu queria saber se é possível, ou me informem pelo menos o caminho do norte, uma forma de eu salvar informações do tipo Endereço, telefones e talz. Tipo, que não precise de um "loop"

Sei que posso estar redondamente enganado, e os post type e loops sirvam perfeitamente para isso. Mas por exemplo, eu tenho q repetir o endereço e telefones em vários lugares de um tema, qual seria a forma mais correta de fazer isso?

o problema é que me falta vocabulário pra perguntar e até procurar esse tipo de solução.

Comment: Se um dia você quiser desistir do wordpress, este CMS é bem legal: http://grabaperch.com. Pelo que você disse, pode funcionar pro seu perfil. É pago, mas a licença é barata e você pode cobrar do seu cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta foi meio confusa porque pode ter várias respostas dependendo do uso desses dados.

Se os dados que você quer repetir diversas vezes no tema nunca serão alterados, você pode usar a implementação direta no código. Isso pode funcionar se você quer inserir uma informação que o usuário do tema não vai mudar de lugar nem a informação. Tudo que precisa fazer é criar um arquivo php e inclui-lo onde quiser no tema, desde que o local aceite uma saída direta de html.

Digamos que a informação é:

Endereço: Rua dos bobos, nº0
Telefone: (99) 32345678"

Você deve criar o arquivo "info.php":

```
<?php 
echo 'Endereço: Rua dos bobos, nº0 <br/>
Telefone: (99) 32345678';
?>
```

E incluí-lo:

```
<?php include 'caminho_para_o_arquivo/info.php'; ?>
```

Quando precisar alterar os dados, você pode alterar o info.php e todos os locais onde ele foi incluído serão alterados.

Você pode também incluir esse arquivo a partir de outro local. Isso funciona bem para assinatura de site por exemplo, quando você precisa alterar alguma informação sua em vários sites ao mesmo tempo.

```
<?php include 'https://meusite.tld/info.php'; ?>
```

É importante que essa inclusão seja feita com SSL para que os sites que utilizam SSL não fiquem vulneráveis e apresentem sua informação corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

O que vc quer fazer é mole com esses dois plugins gratuitos: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/
Com esse vc cria por exemplo um Post Type chamado "Agenda".

E com esse outro vc cria os campos 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/
Por exemplo telefone, imagem, endereço, url do site, etc.
E então quando criar os campos ACF vc diz que serão usados no Post Type "Agenda".

A documentação de ambos os plugins acima é bem completa. Dominando eles vc faz isso ai em questão de minutos com o WordPress!